# Service Area with lines and polygons as starting point

Tags: qgis, distance, network, network-analysis, service-area

I have a file with schools and kindergartens represented as points and a network line file. I'm using the QGIS 3.22 Network Analysis 'Service Area from Layer' tool to create a line output which contains given network distances from the schools and kindergartens.

Now, I need to do the same for built up areas, which are represented as polygons and for bus lines which are represented as lines. Is there a QGIS tool or plugin that does this for polygons and lines - either creates a line output showing the network distance or creates an isodistance layer?

Comment: Extract vertices and use this layer as input. For polygons, create the intersection of polygons with network  and extract vertices of this intersection.

Comment: Is there no plugin that does this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this"? Extracting vertices? Why would you need a plugin for this?

Comment: Extracts vertices and creates an isodistance layer.

Comment: This is a special workflow for your task, I doubt anyone created a plugin for exactly this task. What you can do is create a model with graphic modeler if you need to run repeatedly the same workflow.